# Magento 2. When does the cart become inactive?

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

I'm looking at `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface::getIsActive`

- I see there is a setter on this as well so the value can be changed by hand.
- By default when does this value change? What `event/scenario` triggers the cart to become *not active* anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on **Quote Lifetime (days)** which you can configured from admin panel.

You can find the settings in

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart

[image]